# Is there a unix signal that corresponds to process death in Android?

Tags: android, unix, android-ndk

I'm trying to catch a Unix signal to identify a process death i.e the user removed the app from recents.
Tried to catch `SIGTERM` but it seems unrelated to the matter.
So, which Unix signal can be caught for a case like this one ?

Answer (score 0):

The are several types of signals, defined in the <sys/signals.h> C header file, that might be used by the OS to terminate a process. You can check [this page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for the list of the standard ones.

In your case, to detect the Unix signal received, you should check the macros defined in <sys/wait.h> C header file, e.g. WTERMSIG/WSTOPSIG. For example with the following code:

```
int status, pid;
pid = wait(&status);    
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("child exited with status %d", WEXITSTATUS(status));
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
    printf("child killed by signal %d", WTERMSIG(status));
    if (WCOREDUMP(status))
        printf("core dumped");
} else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
    printf("child stopped by signal %d", WSTOPSIG(status));
}
```